# Créate isolated thread like an process

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I créate an dll and it internal use an com object 
when the dll method is invoked a thread is created with setapartmentstate sta.

The problem are the cookies in webbrowser it is shared.

So if user enter and start a session And after user 2 enter. user 1 and 2 shared the same session my option is created a console application and invoked it with processstartinfo for created a new process and prevent share cookies

But it have other implications how return result to the correct process in the web server or have use database for save temporarily the result,

So some know if is possible create an thread like do ProcessStartInfo?

Some idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i resolve with

1) create an console application and invoked that with Process and procccestartinfo and with waithforall wait for finallization

2) for comunication all information is serialized using newtownjson

3) after read the serialized response and return the result

Simple by ugly. but work